# how to make a date range with created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get the total number of Profile views created within the last 30 days in my Rails app. The code below is producing a result of '0' when it's expected to be '1' (i.e. I viewed the profile once). I'm wondering if I did something wrong with the range. Rails is not throwing an error.

```
 @profileviews = Profileview.where({:user_id => @user.id, :created_at => (Date.today)..(Date.today - 30)}).count
```

Note, the profileview I'm expecting it to include in the count was created today.

`created_at: "2013-05-31 14:43:55"`

Comment: with the code from someone's deleted comment `:created_at => ((Date.today - 30)...Date.today)`It's still showing '0.' Note, the profile view I'm expecting it to include in the count was created today.

Comment: saw this after I posted my answer. Can you post the query that is being executed? Adding .to_sql at the end, instead of .count will produce that.

Comment: to_sql is neat trick: `SELECT "profileviews".* FROM "profileviews" WHERE "profileviews"."user_id" = 56 AND ("profileviews"."created_at" BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-31') times`

Comment: This is the created_at for the Profileview that it should be including  `created_at: "2013-05-31 14:43:55"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your range is backwards, it needs to go from low to high:

```
:created_at => (Date.today - 30)..(Date.today)
```

Comment: I posted the sql in the comments to the OP. Note the profile view (that I'm hoping to include in the count) was created today

Comment: maybe it's just a time of day issue? (after I get the date range in the correct order) this is the created_at for the profileview i expected it to include `created_at: "2013-05-31 14:43:55"`

Comment: I would probably just do Date.today.end_of_day

Comment: using `Time.now` instead of `Date.today` in the second half of the range made the difference (once I got them in the right order). Thanks for your help.